# Can I force update of a Control via EventTrigger to another databound Control's "LostFocus" event?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, eventtrigger

I have a `Person` class which does not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. My ViewModel has a property of type `Person`. In my View, one of the panels has `MyViewModel.SelectedPerson` as `DataContext`, so I bind some `TextBox`es to `Weight`, `Height` and `BodyMassIndex` properties.

It so happens that `BodyMassIndex` is calculated from `Weight` and `Height`, but since `Person` doesn't notify its own changes, everytime I edit one of `Height` or `Weight`, `BodyMassIndex` doesn't update.

My question is: How could I request a "refresh" of `textboxBodyMassIndex` Text property using an EventTrigger (or any appropriate other way) which "listens" to the other two textboxes "ValueChanged" event?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: If you can, implement INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: You could simply add a TextChanged event on the other two TextBoxes.

Comment: @Tony TexBoxes in WPF already have a `TextChanged` event, I just don't know how to use it in a DataTrigger to update the other TextBox... Also, I plan to follow the strategy of DomainObjects that don't notify their property changes, at least while I can (ViewModels should do this)

Comment: Triggers are mainly for setting styles and activating animations. For what you want to do, just write an event handler and attach it to both textboxes. But this is not the best approach because it makes for a stronger dependency between the UI elements and the data.

Comment: @nmclean I also think that adding "entity logic" in the view is a bad approach... Do you suggest an alternative, say, adding code at the viewmodel level (event, most probably) to achieve the desired behavior?

Comment: wrap all model properties in the ViewModel and have the ViewModel notify their changes or perform calculations or whatever.

Comment: @HighCore that seems a good approach (almost evident, now that it has been written down...). Would you put it in an answer, perhaps? With some simple example code, so that I could accept it?

Answer (score 1):

Create an extended person class (or partial to the existing for generated code as another option) which inherits from the person class and implements INotifyPropertyChanged. The new class has 'extended' properties which are based on (and change) the original properties but report the On Notify for the updating of the screen as required. The view then is bound to the extended properties which in code change the original properties; so the work is seamless.